# PHP dynamic table

Tags: php

I have to make a dynamic table n*n , the user first gives the number n and the program makes a 5*5 table with check box this part I have make it, the second part is the user checks same of the checkbox and clicks on submit and the program makes again a table 5*5 but in the place of check box which checks is colored. I have uploaded and image.
Sorry for my bad English, thanks for your time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxMBd.png)

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Give value">
</form>

<?php

$rows = $cols = $name = "";

if(isset($_GET['subject']))
$rows = $cols = $_GET['subject']; 
if(isset($_POST['check_list']))
$name = $_POST['check_list'];

if(isset($_GET['subject'])){

echo "<form action='my.php' method='post'>";
echo "<table border='1'>";
for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){

    echo "<tr>";
        for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
               echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='value ".$td."'></td>";

        }
   echo "<tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
 echo "<input type='submit' />
</form>";

}

// this part of code is not make the third excecution the number 3 image 
echo $cols; 
echo "<table border='1'>";

for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){

    echo "<tr>";
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $value){
               if($tr == $value[td])echo "<td bgcolor='#FF0000'></td>";
               else
                   echo "<td> </td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";



?>
```

Comment: You have a description of what your code should do, and a bunch of code. I miss the part where you explain what is going wrong.

Comment: The lats to loop is not make the third excecution the number 3 image

Comment: What is the value of `$rows`? Also, I would advise you to check if it is a number - what if someone enters "cheese"?